# Not able to logon Magento Admin

Tags: php, magento

Dears,
I have a question - hope someone can pinpoint me in the correct direction.
One friend of mine has a physical shop, and now wants to deploy a webshop. They have hired a Magento consultant.

But a week before the webshop is about to go live, a crash happens. The following error is returned, when trying to logon the Magento admin panel. The webpage is rendered useless.

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => filemtime(): stat failed for /var/www/vhosts/[hidden_domain.name]/httpdocs/app/code/local/Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php(4) : eval()'d code
    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/[hidden_domain.name]/httpdocs/app/code/local/Extendware/EWCore/Model/Autoload.php(4) : eval()'d code
    [line] => 2
)
```

The consultant wants to start again from scratch. I have said no, and I am in the process of getting full access to the server.

I know databases, and I know PHP - but do not know Magento.

Can anyone tell me in what direction I should start looking, when I get full access to the server? I am guessing this is something with permissions in the linux system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was maybe straight forward for someone knowing magento.
Adminhtml folder was changed from lowercase to uppercase.

No idea why. From now on, all my installations will be found in a git to trace stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow given instruction, this step magento 1.7.x.x and 1.9.x.x version**

> Step 1 : Please connect ftp and locate this file path :-
>   app/etc/modules/Extendware.xml (Please find here exact Extendware.xml or realative word file)
>
> Step 2 : Open this file find this line :  `<active>true</active>`
>   Please make replace to this line of code : `<active>false</active>`
>
> Step 3 : Please save the file and upload and reload the browser or open the URL in private window
>
> Step 4: If you still facing the same issue please rename the cache file.
>   Find file on root location `var/` now rename cache file and reload your browser once again.

*Hope it's help to you, If you still problem please send me URL of your site, I will check from my side.*